# XCode 8.1 header include non-modular header

Tags: ios, react-native, swift3, ios-frameworks

I'm in the process of creating a IOS React Native framework built using Swift 3. The framework has React Native as a project library included. However, when I add the necessary `#import "RCTBridgeModule.h"` to be default headers file for the framework in order to use classes such as `RCTPromiseResolveBlock`.. the build fails with an error stating:

> Include of non-modular header inside framework module 'ProjectSDK'
>   Could not build Objective-C module 'Project SDK'

Any ideas on how to fix this?